# Trigger Automator workflow on HDD mount

Tags: data-synchronization, automator, rsync

I want to know if there is some way to trigger a workflow when an external HDD is plugged.

I want to mirror one folder in my local machine to backup it. Target folder will be in the external HDD and I would like it to trigger everytime the HDD is mounted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've come with a small script to rsync the two folders

```
#!/bin/bash

# target folder
TARGET_VOLUME="/Volumes/Data/";
TARGET_FOLDER="Pictures/Lightroom/";
TARGET=${TARGET_VOLUME}${TARGET_FOLDER};

if [ ! -d $TARGET ]
then
    echo "ERROR: Folder $TARGET_FOLDER in Volume: $TARGET_VOLUME not found";
    exit;
else
    echo "Backing up Lightroom catalog...";
    rsync -aE --delete ~/${TARGET_FOLDER} $TARGET;
    echo "Done!";
fi
```

Then using LaunchControl I've created a new file with only the path to the script and the action StartOnMount and an interval of 86400 so I guess it will run once a day or everytime I plug my external HDD.

Probably not the best solution but it seems to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just popped open Automator to see if any actions are available that could be strung together to do this. It looks to me like this is something that you would need to create using Apple Script.

Take a look at the this forum thread:
http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=115494

The post by rccharles has example apple script that could be used to accomplish this. The other posts above this one also have some alternate suggestions that could do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you snortch. I've actually written a bash script to do the task and learning how to run it with launchd which seems to be the most common way. I'll post the solution here

Answer (score 0):

Using http://www.controlplaneapp.com should make it possible to quite easily do this (using a Mount Volume rule combined with an Action)